# Is it possible to manipulate remote (on server) xml/txt database file via Silverlight application?

Tags: c#, linux, silverlight, ssh, ftp

I don't have possibility to use Microsoft SQL Server. Is it possible to **manipulate remote (on linux-based server) xml/txt database file via Silverlight application**?  Can I use FTP or SSH file transfer to do it? How to do it? Would it be safe? 
I know the solution with PHP + MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can change remote files from Silverlight application using SFTP (the easiest way) or FTP. There exist components for remote FTP and/or SSH/SFTP access to remote files for Silverlight (our SecureBlackbox is one of examples).

The only problem you'll encounter is loss of concurrency -- from server's point of view you are modifying the local file from remote side. Other clients can't synchronize their modifications with your client, and this can cause troubles.

Another possible limitation is in the ways you access the file structure. I.e. if your component which you use to work with the database requires some particular method to access files, then you can have problems emulating this method. And if the component works with Stream interface, then there should be no significant problems.